# Logarithmic equations in one variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

If $\log x\cdot y^3 =m$ and $\log x^3\cdot y^2=p$, then find $\log (\frac{x^2}{y})$.

Please show all the steps necessary to solve the above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the basis of the logarithms?

Comment: Please use
[MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 
to format math on this site.

Comment: In the future, please include your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties you faced that got you stuck.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Recall that if $b, u, v > 0$, with $b \neq 1$, then $\log_b(\frac{u}{v}) = \log_b u - \log_b v$.  Then $\log x^3y^2 - \log xy^3 = $

Answer (score 1):

To solve this you need to remember the properties of logarithms. $$ \log(ab) = \log(a) +\log(b) $$

And

$$ \log(a^b) = b \cdot \log(a) $$

Using these two rules you can rewrite "m" and "p" as:

$$ m= \log(x)+3 \cdot \log(y) $$
$$ p=3 \cdot \log(x)+2 \cdot \log(y) $$

From here you can rearrange and solve not for "x" and "y" but for "log(x)" and "log(y)". Remember you are looking for $ \log(x^2/y) = 2 \cdot \log(x) - \log(y)$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Formatting tip:  Type `$\log x$` to obtain $\log x$.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.